# IPv6 address assignment in the 0::/8 range

Tags: python, networking, ipv6

I need to know if the address in the range 0::/96 can be actually assigned in IPv6 or not. 
I've found the reference on IANA that IANA can't assign that range (actually 0::/8 range) but I can't find it as being an actually "reserved" range. 
My issue is that I'm converting IP Addresses from integers on python. Using the standard library ipaddress which has a convenient factory method `ip_address` that applies the simple heuristic, if n < 2**32 then ipv4 else ipv6.

This heurisitc would be great if I could find a place in which it screams out to networks admins to forbid using this range xD

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: IANA does call it a Reserved range. See _[Internet Protocol Version 6 Address Space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml)_: **0000::/8 Reserved by IETF**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find what you are looking for in [RFC 5156](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5156). Section [2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5156#section-2.3) lists the "IPv4-Compatible Addresses" which have been deprecated:

> These addresses are deprecated and should not appear on the public Internet

And if you should see them they represent an IPv4 address (except for `::1`), so a `n > 1 && n < 2**32` heuristic should be perfectly safe.